# EmberJS DS.PromiseObject vs DS.PromiseArray

Tags: ember.js, ember-data

This is my fist time out with Ember and I am trying to retrieve data from a REST api. When I use the following call to find() in my controller it works:

```
this.set('episode', this.store.find('episode', 1);
```

This returns a DS.PromiseObject and the bound input controls in the template are updated to reflect the returned values.

However, when I use the following call to find(), using a query:

```
this.set('episode', this.store.find('episode', {anotherField: x});
```

This returns a DS.PromiseArray and the bound controls in the template do not update.

I am only expecting this call to return a single record and do not know the ID so I am unable to use the first example which works.

How could I access the underlying records in the DS.PromiseArray from the controller?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

just wait for the promise to resolve, then set the first record to episode.  When you find by query client side you are unaware of the amount of results that will return.  So it gives you a collection, which can be 0+ records.  Unlike by id where it knows it's a single record, hence the two different types of proxies.

```
var self = this;
this.store.find('episode', {anotherField: x}).then(function(results){
  self.set('episode', results.get('firstObject'));
});
```